Ms Access form searchbox too slow when recorset type is dynaset
I have a split form in datasheet view. The build-in search box at the bottom of the form is been used frequently frοm users. If the form's RecordsetType=Snapshot then the searching is very quick. If RecordsetType=Dynaset then is very slow.
I made my own textbox as search box with the following code. There has been improvement but not like when RecodsetType=Snapshot:
Private Sub txtSearch_Change()
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Dim searchText As String
    Dim sql As String
    searchText = Me.txtSearch.Text
    
    Dim rs As Recordset 'default DAO recordset
    Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
    rs.FindFirst "[f1] like '*" & searchText & "*'"
    If Not rs.NoMatch Then
        Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
    Else
        MsgBox "Not Found!"
    End If
    Me.txtSearch.SetFocus
    Me.txtSearch.SelStart = Len(searchText)
Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.description
End Sub


The form has AllowAdditons=False and only one check field has the need to update. So I thought to search to find if I can have datasheet or continuous unbound form and to manipulate the update to only one field through VBA. But I have found only for single forms.
UPDATE

I found this. But it doesn't say if it is about single or continuous form or datasheet. And it doesn't say about recordset type. I tried it and it doesn't work.


The ideal would be to have snapshot bound form with editable controls and to save changes we use vba issuing sql UPDATE with current connection. But when it is in snapshot the controls are not editable.


The ideal would be to have snapshot bound form with editable controls and to save changes we use vba issuing sql UPDATE with current connection.

You could try forcing the dynaset form to load its full recordset when opening, by adding Me.RecordsetClone.MoveLast to Form_Load. This can be helpful for combo boxes, I'm not sure it will make a difference here.

If its only a checkbox you need modified then go with a snapshot form and build-in search. Then add a button to toggle the checkbox value via code.

First I am on datasheet view. So command buttons can't be viewed (Of course it could be a link). Second it is not so intuitive for end users. What if I need in the future a second field?

I thought you had a continuous form. So with a datasheet, you could include your datasheet as a subform and have the unbound main form perform edits on the selected row via unbound controls.

If your goal is to update the found record, use RecordsetClone as a dynaset:
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
rs.FindFirst "[f1] like '*" & searchText & "*'"
If Not rs.NoMatch Then
    Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
    ' Update checkbox:
    rs.Edit
    rs!CheckBoxField.Value = True
    rs.Update
Else
    MsgBox "Not Found!"
End If
rs.Close

The form field will be updated as well.

First if the recordset type is snapshot the RS.edit will not work. The recordset is not updateable! Second no there is not connection between the two. Your code updates the field every time the user change the content of search box and find that content!!!

First, as noted, use a dynaset. Next, we don't know what and when you wish to update, so use this as a skeleton and adjust as needed. The core is, that it is way faster to update the RecordsetClone than to run a separate query followed by a requery of the form.

Sorry. You really mentioned about dynaset. But you answered to a differed question. I do not need to update when I find! It is separated the two functions as I said.

But even if I wanted something like that I don't think that the recorsetclone of the nonupdateable recodset is updateable. It would be very strange and inconsistent. We talk about snapshot form to have quick search.

Sure. The form must be updateable.
